# :SQL how to count the amount of distinct rows the have a multiple if column in common( that is joined from from another table)

Tags: sql, join, count, distinct

Ok, so here is my question. Maybe my brain is just fried, but im struggling to wrap my head around this

i have one table(lets say TableA with a set of columns, lets say there names are:

pk1, Pk2, a, b, c,APPLE(has 3 set values from another table), etc                  (the PK1 and PK2 are primary keys)

and then I have another table(lets say tableB)

PK1(is linked with PK1 on TableA), ag, DOG, sf, STAR(also has a set nr of values),etc

Ok, so now i want to join these 2 tables, thats the easy part.  the values in PK1 can repeat, as long as the combination of PK1 and PK2 are unique,and this is the case.

ok, here comes the tricky part.  i want get a list of of the distinct combinations of PK1+PK2+a

but i also want to know how many of them are of each type of STAR.

**ok, this part is optional(for you bright sparks out there):**

and just to really make it tricky, each type of star must then be sub divided into types of APPLES

1) how do i do this?
2) is it possible to do it with just 1 query, i will i have to use something like a cursor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What have you tried? Maybe this can help?

```
select distinct pk1,pk2,a from tableA
```

,

```
select tableA.pk1,pk2,a,star,count(*)
from tableA join tableB on tableA.pk1 = tableB.pk1
group by tableA.pk1,pk2,a,star
```

,

```
select tableA.pk1,pk2,a,star,apples,count(*)
from tableA join tableB on tableA.pk1 = tableB.pk1
group by tableA.pk1,pk2,a,star,apples
```

Comment: arg, that was stupid of me. how do I forget about group by? Guess it was cause my brain was so damn tired.hehe

Comment: question thought, just wondering if its possible. it is grouped now basically nicely for the star and apples.  but it is on 2 different rows(which is good). but I was wondering. how difficult it would be to  put it in 1 row. like xxxxxxxxxxx 2star1apple  1star2apple.  im going to go see if i can figure it out myself aswell, but just thought I would post it here as well as a brain teaser

Comment: by the way, i tried to use DISTINCT instead of GROUP BY. GROUP BY totally just slipped my mind

Comment: i decided that its WAAAAAAY to much extra effort for the little gain that you get for putting it in row